Algebraic independence and substitution for quadratics
Let $f_{1},...,f_{n-1} \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $\{ f_1,..., f_{n-1},x_n \}$ is algebraically independent over $\mathbb{F}$. Let $G \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_{n-1}]\smallsetminus \mathbb{F}[x_1,...,y_1,...,y_{n-1}]$ (i.e. $G$ is not $x_n$-free). Then is $\{ f_1,....,f_{n-1}, G(x_1,...,x_n, f_1,...,f_{n-1}) \}$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{F}$?
Moreover assume that $f_1,...f_{n-1},G(x_1,...,x_n)$ are all quadratics and linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}$.

What do you mean by "is not $x_n$ free"?

I mean $G \notin \mathbb{F}[x_1,....,x_{n-1},y_1,...,y_{n-1}]$

Can’t you just take $f_i=x_ix_n$ and $G=x_1x_n$?

@JeremyRickard, you are right. That's a good counter-example. The specific application I have in mind was $f_{1},...,f_{n-1}, G(x_1,...,x_n,f_1,....,f_{n-1})$ were all quadratic and linearly independent. I will update to the special case. A general principle might not exist.
